# Euler Method in Java, Variable Initial Condition

Tags: java, math, physics, differential-equations, calculus

How would I write the Euler method in Java for a variable initial condition? For example, the initial condition that `y(w)=0`.

The equation I'm trying to solve is:

```
dy/dx = (y-sqrt(x^2 + y^2))/x
```

My initial code is simple.

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class euler 
{

    public static void main(String arg[]) 
    {
        int N = 10;

        double h = 1.0/N;
        double x0 = w;       //This is what I would like to put in
        double y0 = 0;   

        double x = x0, y = y0;

        for (int i=0;i < N;i++)  
        {
            y += h*f(x, y);
            x += h;

            System.out.println("x, y = " + x + ", " + y);
        }
    }

    static double f(double x, double y) 
    {
        return((y-Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)))/x);
    }

}
```

My code should work for any kind of integer value of x0, but how could I get it to work for a variable w?

Answer (score 0):

You get not only one solution, you get a family of solutions parametrized by the initial condition. Through every point `(x0,y0)` there is a solution, some, but not all, will give the same solution.

Thus `y(w)=0` resp. the pair `(x0=w, y0=0)` will give a solution for every `w`, there is nothing to solve to get a specific value of `w`.

?? Could `w` stand for `omega` and that for infinity ?? That would be a valid question, to control the asymptotic behavior.

---

The only critical point of this problem is `x=0`, and even that only for `y(0)<0`, since then the differential equation has a singularity.